# Как правильно объединить производителей и категории

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте. У меня такая структура бд.

```
categories  |  products  |  brands
name           name         name
slug           slug         slug
               category_id  
               brand_id
```

Я хочу сделать фильтер по производителям (обычный фильтер как в любом интернет магазине). Но, так как производители не относятся к категориям, приходится делать так: беру массив товаров, которые находятся в категории (к примеру) холодильники, а потом делую так

```
/**
 * Получаем производителей
 *
 * @param array $ids
 * @return mixed
 */
public function brands($ids = [])
{
    return Brand::whereHas('products', function($q) use($ids)
    {
        $q->whereIn('id', $ids);
    }
    )->get();
}
```

Это все работает, пока я не перейду по какому нибудь фильтру.
Вопрос собственно в том, как по другому вывести производителей в категорию? На английском стаке мне посоветовали отнести производителей к категории. Но тут возникает другая проблема. Придется каждый раз выбирать, к какой категории относится производитель. Есть ли какое нибудь универсальное решение?

Comment: Прав**и**льнее буд**е**т задать корректный вопрос. Сейчас абсолютно непонятно, что вам нужно и что не получается.

Comment: @ArchDemon изменил вопрос, надеюсь теперь более понятно обьяснил)

Comment: На чистом SQL будет что то типа `select * from brands where id in(select brand_id from products where category_id=нужная_категория)`

Comment: вам @Mike правильно ответил. Я бы только добавил `SELECT DISTINCT brand_id`. Проблема в том, что такой запрос будет выполняться медленно при большой базе. Можно как вам уже сказали сделать промежуточную таблицу, где перечислить все категории производителя.

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Ваш код запрос помог. Только пришлось сделать такой запрос `select * from `hp_brands` where exists (select * from `hp_products` where `hp_products`.`brand_id` = `hp_brands`.`id` and `category_id` = '23')` ибо как у вас, на laravel-е не получится наверное.

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо, попробую с `DISTINCT` запрос. А по поводу промежуточной таблицы, я думаю так не удобно будит. Пример: Есть производитель Bosch, он в основном быт технику производит. Вот я свяжу его со всеми категориями и подкатегориями быт техники, а потом допустим добавлю новую категорию где тоже будит Bosch, придется редактировать производителя и привящывать его к новой категории, и так с каждым производителе. Не удобно)

Comment: @ArchDemon А я бы distinct не добавлял. IN без дистинкта оптимизатор может превратить в join и он на самом деле понимает, что одинаковые значения смысла не имеют. А distinct может запутать оптимизатор и привести к группировке. Хотя MySQL у меня на тестовой табличке строит вообще одинаковые планы и с дистинком и без. А в старых ораклах distinct замедлял.